# Method signature including the throws exception?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, functional-interface, throws

I know the *method signature* is including **method name** and its **parameter list**.

**But how about `throws Exception`?**

```
public List<ServiceStatusVo> listServiceStatuses() throws RetrieverException {
    ...
    return list;
}
```

If it's not included then why I **cannot** pass in the following lambda:

```
() -> listServiceStatuses()
```

but I can pass in

```
() -> {
    try {
        return listServiceStatuses();
    } catch (RetrieverException e) {
    }
}
```

And also I can **throw** it out again

```
() -> {
    try {
        return listServiceStatuses();
    } catch (RetrieverException e) {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I know the `Supplier<T>` functional interface, that's what really confusing me **if** **throws** is not part of the **method signature**.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Seems like you've answered your own question, no? Supplier.get() does not throw any checked exceptions, so a lambda that throws a checked exception would not conform to the required type.

Comment: @jspcal I just feel it that way, but till now I did not find out any official doc to specify it. Would you provide some details?

Comment: Fully described hire http://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions

Comment: @VictorGubin I know that post describing how to handle this case, but what I wanna know here is **why**?

Comment: @Hearen I do believe it is all about [no side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)) [functional programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) idiom. Exception racing is really - a side effect. Lambdas is an idea from functional  programming added to imperative language as an addition.

Comment: @VictorGubin not really, there is nothing to stop a lambda throwing a checked exception (e.g. `interface CheckedSupplier<T, E> { T get() throws E; }`); you just can't throw it for the `Supplier` type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not about the method signature directly. From [JLS Sec 11.2.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2.3):

> It is a compile-time error if a lambda body can throw some exception class E when E is a **checked exception** class **and** E is **not a subclass** of some class declared in the throws clause of the function type targeted by the lambda expression.

This is a little surprising - I must admit that my initial thought was that the exception *is* part of the method signature.

But remember that "checked exception" means [*compile-time checked exception*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-11.html#jls-11.2): the compiler makes sure that you have handled all checked exceptions; but once it has been compiled, checked and unchecked exception types are treated just the same. Notice that that [the JVM spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se9/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.10) doesn't even mention checkedness in the section on exceptions.

So, as seen at runtime, the method can throw any exception. And as stated in the language spec:

> Two methods or constructors, M and N, have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types.